# Looping through perl constant

Tags: perl, loops, constants

I have the following code in perl:

```
 package SignatureScheme;

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use constant {
      SHA256_RSA_V1 => 'SHA256-RSA-V1',
      SHA256_HMAC_V1 => 'SHA256-HMAC-V1',
  };
```

How can I loop through the constants listed above and compare them to a string?

Comment: why?  what are you doing with that string?  can you change the module, or are you trying to do this without changing it?

Comment: I am trying to write a forName (java) equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @schemes = (SHA256_RSA_V1, SHA256_HMAC_V1);

foreach my $scheme (@schemes) {
  if ($scheme eq $string) {
      # do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Is $scheme automatically converted to string type when compared?

Comment: It's already string type, since that's what the values of the constants are.

Comment: Fixed answer to use `eq` for string comparison

Comment: Oh you mean in addition to defining the constant like I have defined, I have to use your code to do the comparison?

Comment: It's just example code. The only important thing is the definition of `@schemes`. That's a list of all the values of the constants. Do the comparisons any way you want.

Comment: @Barmar - constants don't have "values". They are implemented as subroutines.

Comment: The values returned by the subroutines will be put in `@schemes`. Once you create that list, it doesn't matter where the data came from.

Comment: @Barmar - that last comment is a lot more technically correct than your first one ;)

Answer (score 2):

For one-time comparison:

```
my $string = "xyz";
my $found = grep ($_ eq $string) (SHA256_RSA_V1, SHA256_HMAC_V1);
```

**Constants are merely subroutines returning your strings**, therefore you can use them alomst anywhere  where you would have used the strings themselves.

For repeated comparisons, to improve performance, use hash lookups.

```
my %lookup_hash = map {($_=>1)} (SHA256_RSA_V1, SHA256_HMAC_V1);
foreach my $lookup_string (@lookup_strings) {
    if ($lookup_hash{$lookup_string}) {  #do your thing }
}
```